# How to keep FTP connection (or any connection object) alive between activities

Tags: android, ftp, android-activity

I'm coding a very basic FTP client on top of my application and I have 2 activities. The first one is the file explorer and the second one is the image viewer. Once I click on the image filename on the explorer, I want to pass the connection to the other activity to handle extra stuff. Basically, I want to keep the same `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient` object (which handles the connection) alive in-between the 2 activities. I know I can't pass an object inside an intent so I don't know what my best bets are.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend yout application class and code the ftp connection there, every time you need to use it call the Application

```
public class FtpConnect extends Application {

//FTP CODE

}
```

where ever you need to use it

```
FtpConnect singleFtpHandler = (FtpConnect) CurrentActivityClass.this.getApplication();              
singleFtpHandler.method();
```

You need to add the appExtender name to your manifest like this:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".FtpConnect">
```

Comment: just in case someone stumbles over this like i did here is a more detailed answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables/708317#708317